# External JS plugins don't work after AJAX post

Tags: ajax

i've created a little admin dashboard that loads the pages using ajax calls but when i output the post result to the parent/container DIV i can't bind the elements with the native plugins such as : datepickers, character textbox count, ...I've tried to use `$getScript` function after the AJAX success, refreshing the scripts and searching for similar cases but nothing.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank You!

---

Here's the code I use to load the body content, it just get the page by its ID :

```
function load_page(id)
            {
             var toId = "";

             $('#ajax-intro-body').show();

             if (id == "dashboard")
                 toId = "../src/pages/partials/" + id + ".php";
             else
                 toId = "../src/pages/" + id + ".php";

             $.ajax({
              url:toId,
              method:"POST",
              data:{},
              success:function(data)
              {
               if (data == "session_expired"){
                   location.replace("../src/pages/login/")
               }else{
                    // Show output data
                    $('#ajax-content').html(data);
                    // Set refresh address id
                    $('.refresh-content').attr('id',id);
                    // Fade out the loading bar body
                    $('#ajax-intro-body').fadeOut(100);
                    // Remove animation from sync
                    $('#refresh-icon').removeClass("fa-spin");
               }
              }
             });
            }
```

While in the *head* i've inserted the plugins, for example here, this plugin should limit and count the character of an input inside a partial PHP page:

```
<script src="assets/js/e_textarealimiter.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

In the end in the PHP partial there are just a form with some inputs.

Comment: you have to initialize the plugins after you output the html. and please share some code or content so we can get clear image of your problem, share your ajax etc

Comment: You right here it this, hope it will help

Comment: after you added html, initialize plugins, like $('.date-picker').datepicker(); etc

Comment: Cool the problem was also i made some mistakes inside the jquery plugin assign. Thank You!